# error in django called module not found

Tags: python, django

I made one project called `mysite` and I created using startapp called books.I made the admin site and it worked successfully. But when I tried to add models to my admin site the error occurred mentioning these things.

```
ImportError at /admin/
No module named books.models
```

Actually I created `admin.py` in books folder and then I wrote the following code.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mysite.books.models import Publisher, Author, Book

admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book)
```

#### models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: try using only `from models import Publisher, Author, Book` instead.

Comment: What is the django version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead..

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Publisher, Author, Book

admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try

```
from books.models import Publisher, Author, Book
...
```

if books is the name of your app